# Can we do Gayatri japam without its being part of Sandhyavandanam?

Tags: time, gayatri-mantra, scripture

I don't mean to ask whether we can skip sandhyavandanam and do Gayatri japam instead. I know we can't.

Say, I feel like doing the japam at around 3 or 4 p.m. Is that allowed?

Comment: Yeah, as long as your do your required Sandhyavandanam, yeah you can certainly say the Gayatri mantra at other times as well.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I agree that we can do japa after or before sandhya kala. but we should rembember certain rules like Asaucha,Physical Purity, we should not do japa after Sunset i.e after Sayam Sandhyavandana. Prefered timing for japa is Sandhyakala. A person should be initiated into savitri/gyatri of particular varna.